# TFS 2015- Test cases duplication with different configuration- Configuration option is not seen

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

In TFS 2015, I can see duplication of test cases with same ids but different configurations. Some forums, say to deselect the configuration from the test suit to avoid this.
But the real problem is, though I'm a project admin for the Team project and also the TFS admin, I don't see any options associated with configurations anywhere in the settings. On right clicking the test suit no option to assign/deselect configuration is seen for me.It's just the export, assign tester and other options seen on right click.
Please advise on how this duplication can be resolved
(I'm a new user in the project and not sure on who created the configurations initially and assigned if for the test suit)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that manage Test configuration in Test Hub is available in TFS 2017 and later. Check here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#test-configuration-management-in-test-hub

In TFS 2015, you need to use **Microsoft Test Manager** to manage the configurations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. That was a great help,indeed.